# What to do when you figure out the answer to a question moments after asking it?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I answer my own questions, even those where I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

I've just asked [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263523/passing-user-input-values-through-querystring-without-code-behind) and as I clicked to submit it for answers, I realized how to solve the problem mentioned in the question (the answer relies on information that I have that I didn't put in the post, specifically, other elements in the web pages mentioned).

So now that I have the solution, what do I do with the question now? Clearly deleting it is a bad idea for me...

I assume that I just answer it myself and fill in the blanks that I mentioned above?

Comment: Yeah, you should do that thing you said.